# A lot of random NAT tables appear

Tags: networking, router, macbook, nat, denial-of-service

My brothers Mac seems to be infected. It keeps on sending UDP and SYN floods to our router, and it multiplies my ping 10 times.When I look in the NAT Mapping table there are a lot of random address mappings to his laptop, like 800 or more of 'em. Should I do a virusscan or could this be the result of something else? Torrenting or whatever?

Comment: There are a number of things that could be happening. When you say you look @ the NAT mapping table - I am guessing you mean the NAT table in the router, correct? What sort of router do you own?  What encryption are you using?   Could you post a picture of the NAT table you are referring to?   If you are seeing a bunch of UDP connections to his laptop, it sounds like he has a bit torrent client running.   However, those connections should NOT be showing up in the NAT table on your router (but would show up if you were to run netstat -an on the command line on his computer)

Comment: The NAT table should be a mapping of MAC addresses to LAN IP addresses that have been handed out by your router to clients requesting an IP via DHCP.   If you see lots of connections in the NAT table, that could be a bad thing.   Everything you have described sounds like bit torrent traffic tho.   If you run the netstat command on your brothers mac, could you be so kind as to edit your post and include that info?   It would help get your question answered.